# jquery drop-down menu appears behind other divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have looked at similar questions but no luck fixing it. This is my problem:
[image: Drop down is going behind the div]

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document) .ready(function(){
$('li') .hover(function(){
$(this) .find('ul>li') .stop().fadeToggle(400);
}); 
});
</script>
```

Here are the css sections for the drop down and the box it is hiding behind:

```
ul li li
{
background:#50d7db;
color:#005263;
display:none;
z-index: 5000;
}



#maincontent
{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
opacity:100%;
float:left;
width:815px;
height:390px;
margin-left:15px;
z-index:-5000;
}
```

What I have tried:
- Changing / redoing the z-index values.
- removed opacity from the maincontent div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements. Add `position:relative` to the elements you need to control the `z-index` of.